# SQL stored procedure output params OK on local server, return NULLs when called remotely

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, rpc, linked-server

My stored procedure (`spMyProcA`) has output parameters.  I have a test procedure (`spMyProcA_Test`) that calls `spMyProcA`.  The local variables in the `spMyProcA_Test` are set correctly when I run `spMyProc_Test` on the same server as `spMyProcA`.  The problem I have is when I call the `spMyProcA` from a remote server using a linked server definition, I'm getting nulls. Code pattern is below.

```
-- ON SERVER A (Create)--
CREATE PROC spMyProcA (@id int out) AS
BEGIN
    SET @id = (SELECT MAX([id]) from dbo.someTable)
END
go

-- ON SERVER A (Create & Run there)--
CREATE PROC spMyProcATest AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id int
    EXECUTE dbo.spMyProcA @id out
    SELECT @id  
END
go

EXECUTE dbo.spMyProcATest  -- Success, get the expected results (not null)
go

-- ON SERVER B  (Run there) --
DECLARE @id int

EXECUTE ('EXEC dbo.spMyProcA ?', @id output) AT LinkedAliasForServerA   --REMOTE CALL

SELECT @id  -- FAIL, @id will be NULL

GO
-- ALSO TRIED the following for the REMOTE CALL LINE:
--EXEC ('exec dbo.spMyProcATest @id=? ', @id output) AT LinkedAliasForServerA --Same no-good result as above
--EXEC ('exec dbo.spMyProcATest @id=? output', @id) AT LinkedAliasForServerA --Same no-good result as above
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you configured RPC for the linked server?

First, I ran the following script on my local server, using tempdb as the work space.

The problem with asking the max id from a changing table is locking.  I used least concurrency isolation level with highest degree of accuracy.

You could pick one that matches for business requirements.  Remember, read non committed (no lock) can cause bad answers.

```
-- Just sample code
Use tempdb
go

/*
   Create sample table
*/

-- Delete existing table
IF  EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sys.objects
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[some_table]') AND
    type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[some_table]
GO

-- List objects + columns in master
select 
    o.name + '.' + c.name as obj_name,
    o.xtype,
    row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as obj_id 
into
    dbo.some_table
-- remove (master.) to execute in azure.
from master.sys.all_columns c
join master.sys.sysobjects o on c.object_id = o.id
order by
    o.name,
    c.name
go

-- Show the data
--select * from dbo.some_table
go


/*
   Create sample stored procedure
*/

-- Delete existing procedure
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[spMyProcATest]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyProcATest]
GO

-- SP to grab max id
create procedure dbo.spMyProcATest (@id int out) AS
begin

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
    SELECT @id = MAX(obj_id) FROM dbo.some_table;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
end
go

-- Execute and return result
declare @ret_id int
execute dbo.spMyProcATest @id = @ret_id output
print @ret_id
go
```

[image]

I modified the script and executed it into a sample AZURE SQL DB that contains a database named [BANKING01].  The table was created and I received different but correct results.

[image]

If you forget to enable RPC you will get the following error.

[image]

I am wondering what type of security you are using with the linked server.  This may be causing issues also.  I would run a sql profiler on the linked server to make sure the TDS (tabular data stream) - SQL connection is being made and the query is executing.

Last but not least, I run the Azure SQL DB stored procedure from the remote server and get the correct answers.

[image]

In summary, check the RPC and security for the Linked server.  Depending on the connection, timeouts can be an issue.  Last but not least, remember isolation levels play a part of every transaction.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was in the line:

```
EXECUTE ('EXEC dbo.spMyProcA ?', @id output) AT LinkedAliasForServerA   --REMOTE CALL
```

the corrected version is:

```
EXECUTE ('EXEC dbo.spMyProcA ? OUTPUT', @id output) AT LinkedAliasForServerA   --REMOTE CALL
```